# gradle task create IPA

Tags: ios, gradle, javafx, ipa, gluon-mobile

I try to create IPA of my app by gradle task "createIPA" but it's stopped with this exception:

> Building 88% > :createIpajava.io.FileNotFoundException: No DeveloperDiskImage.dmg found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport for iOS version 10.2 (14C92).
>   Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Are you using the jfxmobile plugin?

Comment: yes, i'm using gluon

Comment: Have you updated XCode recently? What do you have here: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.2`? Do you find a dmg file? What is your XCode version?

Comment: xcode 8.0 version and in the folder there is al version until 10.0, not the 10.2. I have to update xcode?

Comment: I think so, you need to have your iOS version in sync with the XCode one.

Comment: I updated xcode and now it works! thank you!